# ASP.Net Core DI Factory Based on HttpContext

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core

I want the ASP.Net Core IoC container to provide an implementation of an interface based on what view is currently being shown. I figured that I should be able to do this at run time by providing a factory method. In `Startup.cs` I have added the following registration:

```
services.AddTransient<IMyInterface>(serviceProvider => 
{
    var context = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>().HttpContext;

    //Need to switch on current view somehow?
    switch(context.??????){
        case ???:
             return new MyImplementationOne();
        case ???:
             return new MyImplementationTwo():

    }

}
```

How can I use `HttpContext` to switch based on the current view being shown? Or, should I be using some other service available through the `serviceProvider`?

Comment: Have you tried using the request URL? We can't know which view will be shown before the controller action is executed and a view result is returned. And at that point all the dependencies must have already been resolved.

Comment: @juunas I'm new to this: How do I get the request URL? `context.Request` doesn't appear to have a `URL` property on it?

Comment: There is a `Path` property.

Comment: You could use the `IActionContextAccessor` to receive an `ActionContext` instance which contains the controller and action being executed.

Comment: Unfortunately the `Path` property just return `"\"`????

Comment: @HenkMollema How do I get hold of the `IActionContextAccessor`? Doesn't appear to be available in the `serviceProvider`.

Comment: You might have to register it with its implementation (`ActionContextAccessor`)

Comment: The Path would be `/` if you are accessing the root of your app.

Answer (score -1):

Usually you would register a 'Factory' in your DI Container, for example IWhateverServiceFactory...

This would have a method, that takes in the View name (which you can get from the RouteContext) and returns the relevant implementation. This way you can change the logic as to which implementation easily, if for example at some point in the future you want to use a generic implementation.

```
public interface IWhateverServiceFactory{
    IService GetService(String currentViewName);
}

public class DefaultWhateverServiceFactory : IWhateverServiceFactory{
    IService GetService(String currentViewName){
        switch(currentViewName){
        case ???:
             return new MyImplementationOne();
        case ???:
             return new MyImplementationTwo():
        }
    }
}
```

Of the RouteContext doesn't work for you, you can use something like;

```
System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(
            ((RazorView)html.ViewContext.View).ViewPath
        );
```

If you are using Razor to get the views name, or

```
Html.ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");
```

to get the action name...